# table refresh on dropdown value change using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have html table which loaded when page get loaded, and I have dropdown for each column and when I select a value from dropdown the table should refresh for the selected dropdown value.
And I should not be calling any server call, as html table have all data.
Please suggest me on this.

Comment: provide your html and jquery what you have tried

Comment: Put down your code in fiddle ....

Comment: If you are Ok with any third party grid, you can use https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html

Comment: thanks all. is possible to do with using jquery only - no third party plugin. please guide me.

Comment: So in this you may need to manually construct the html or you can follow these steps, 1) Create JS arrays according to your filter 2) Convert this array to HTML by looping through or use any plugins to convert 3) Bind the HTML generated to the container div.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]
and how to create a [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers.
I flagged this question for closing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in this you may need to manually construct the html or you can follow these steps,

1. Create JS arrays according to your filter
2. Convert this array to HTML by looping through or use any plugins to
   convert
3. Bind the HTML generated to the container div.

Or you can follows this as it is explained in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BracketsAcademy/13ko7qg5/)

**HTML**

```
<title>Filter Table</title>

<body>
    <div class="optionsDiv">
        Filter By Position
        <select id="selectField">
            <option value="All" selected>All</option>
            <option value="Student">Student</option>
            <option value="Assistant">Assistant</option>
            <option value="Professor">Professor</option>

        </select>

    </div>
    <table id="myTable">
        <tr id="HeadRow">
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td>Age</td>
            <td>Position</td>
        </tr>

        <tr position="Student">
            <td>John</td>
            <td>John's Last name</td>
            <td>25</td>
            <td>Student</td>
        </tr>

        <tr position="Assistant">
            <td>Timmy</td>
            <td>Timmy's Last name</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>Assistant</td>
        </tr>

        <tr position="Professor">
            <td>Billy</td>
            <td>Billy's Last name</td>
            <td>40</td>
            <td>Professor</td>
        </tr>

        <tr position="Professor">
            <td>Eddy</td>
            <td>Eddy's Last name</td>
            <td>35</td>
            <td>Professor</td>
        </tr>

        <tr position="Professor">
            <td>Emma</td>
            <td>Emma's Last name</td>
            <td>38</td>
            <td>Professor</td>
        </tr>

        <tr position="Student">
            <td>Emily</td>
            <td>Emily's Last name</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>Student</td>
        </tr>

        <tr position="Assistant">
            <td>Jack</td>
            <td>Jack's Last name</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>Assistant</td>
        </tr>

        <tr position="Student">
            <td>Robert</td>
            <td>Robert's Last name</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>Student</td>
        </tr>

        <tr position="Assistant">
            <td>Danny</td>
            <td>Danny's Last name</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>Assistant</td>
        </tr>

        <tr position="Professor">
            <td>Erick</td>
            <td>Erick's Last name</td>
            <td>42</td>
            <td>Professor</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function addRemoveClass(theRows) {

        theRows.removeClass("odd even");
        theRows.filter(":odd").addClass("odd");
        theRows.filter(":even").addClass("even");
    }

    var rows = $("table#myTable tr:not(:first-child)");

    addRemoveClass(rows);


    $("#selectField").on("change", function() {

        var selected = this.value;

        if (selected != "All") {

            rows.filter("[position=" + selected + "]").show();
            rows.not("[position=" + selected + "]").hide();
            var visibleRows = rows.filter("[position=" + selected + "]");
            addRemoveClass(visibleRows);
        } else {

            rows.show();
            addRemoveClass(rows);

        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Sibeesh, Appreciate your help and thanks for quick response. I want filter it by many dropdown(select options), from the example as I seen they constructing  <tr position="Student">, as in example if want filter it out by age, name, last name, what I need do here? as table is static table, and is it I need to construct <tr> having age= and lastname= ?

Comment: @Dayananda Please accept as answer if it helps, that's the ways we say thanks in here :)

Comment: Yes you can try in that way. But as I said in the comment section, this can be pretty much easier if you use any grid plugins. Thanks

Comment: thanks, problem here is I have 14 filters, that's what the problem. lets check is it possible to change example you gave me